# Disable parent QWidget and keep only one child enabled

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

I have a QWidget that has several child items. I want to disable the whole QWidget except for some controls. I tried to achieve this with this code :

```
{
    setEnabled(false);
    ui->targetBox->setEnabled(true);
    ui->switchButton->setEnabled(true);
}
```

but it doesn't work, all controls remain disabled.

Is it possible to achieve this, or am I forced to iterate through all the child widgets manually and disable all of them but the ones I want to keep enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#enabled-prop) state the following:

> Disabling a widget implicitly disables all its children. Enabling respectively enables all child widgets unless they have been explicitly disabled. It it not possible to explicitly enable a child widget which is not a window while its parent widget remains disabled.

As you suspected, disabling a widget disables every child widget and makes them disabled until the parent is enabled.

Thus you do have to manually adjust which component is enabled, and which are disabled.

Answer (score 1):

As you discovered, once a container widget is disabled all its children become greyed out, and it is not possible to re-enable them individually.

In the case where you want to disable all widgets except one, then a solution is to traverse all the ancestors of this widget, and to disable all the sibling widgets at each level.

In this sample code, I stop traversing ancestors when I find a window (for example a `QDialog`).

```
void setEnabledExceptOne(QWidget* w, bool enabled)
{
    if (w->isWindow())
        return;
    QWidget* parent = w->parentWidget();
    if (!parent)
        return;
    for (QWidget* child : parent->findChildren<QWidget*>(QString(), Qt::FindDirectChildrenOnly)) {
        if (child != w)
            child->setEnabled(enabled);
    }
    setEnabledExceptOne(parent, enabled);
}
```